# Regex - Not containing a string and not ending with a /

Tags: javascript, regex, url-rewriting, url-routing

How do I create a regular expression which don't contain the string "umbraco" and doesn't end with a /

This is the what I have so far but I'm unable to get it fully working, any help would be appreciated.

```
(?!umbraco)(?![/]$)
```

Test strings would be:

- http://www.domain.com/umbraco/login.aspx - *shouldn't match*
- http://www.domain.com/pages/1/ - *shouldn't match*
- http://www.domain.com/pages/1 - **should match**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this regex:

```
^(?!.*?umbraco).*?[^\/]$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lM0cS9

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of a line
(?!.*?umbraco) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
umbraco matches the characters umbraco literally (case sensitive)
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
[^\/] match a single character not present in the list below
\/ matches the character / literally
$ assert position at end of a line
```

Comment: @anubhava It will be a great help if you could provide some explanation to the regex you have written

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still matches the second test string.

Comment: Did you check the demo link I provided. It does NOT match 2nd string as it remains white color.

Comment: @aelor: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: The first RegEx you added did but this one seems to be working, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the regex

```
^(?!.*?umbraco).*?[^\/\s*\n*]$
```

demo http://rubular.com/r/tEhY7JFjXK